# Will I miss any opportunities if I tell my employer that I have got another job?

Tags: job-change

I got a job offer, had a chat with my superiors (separately) about being headhunted and my career to date, putting together a plan and some direction.

The company has no issue investing in training me, which is good, but I am wondering if employers see it as a threat to say you've been headhunted. The other thing I'm wondering is if it will mean I miss any opportunities. For example, we have yearly pay increases dependent on company performance, as opposed to personal performance, would I miss those?

Comment: Why on earth would you tell your current employers that you're doing any activity toward getting a new job?

Comment: You're basically fishing for a counteroffer. Given that the consensus is to reject a counteroffer if one is made, going *looking* for one seems an extra level of inadvisable...

Answer (score 5):

Don't go telling people at your current job that you are looking for a new job. Hand in your resignation to your manager *after* you have received a confirmed offer, you have accepted the offer *and* the new employer has acknowledged that you have accepted it.

Your choice of words "I have been headhunted" makes it even more weird. It sounds as though you were not really looking for a new job, but someone forcibly offered you one.

Your concerns are all valid. If the company knows you will be gone soon anyway, there is little incentive for them to invest in you, by way of training or performance bonus. Technically, you could argue that the bonus was for efforts you have already put in, and you would be right, but good luck trying to convince the management to see it that way.